# troubles with drupal routing

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-8

I need to know where Drupal decide what action to perform, depending on what url it receive.
I need to find in drupal 7/8 something like that
in PHP

```
    if(isset($_GET['foo'])) { //do something }
```

or in Flask on Python

```
   @app.route("/goo")
       //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many Symfony components using in Drupal 8 core. You can find any request using Symfony Request class (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request).

In Drupal 8 every module can contain a routing file called MODULE_NAME.routing.yml. You can create your urls with your controller's method. Because Now It support OOP.

There is a nice tools is called DrupalConsole (http://drupalconsole.com). Installation process is very easy. After installing you will be surprise because you will get more useful terminal commands. If you want to see about all urls of drupal 8, you can use like "drupal router:debug" or your can filter your outputs using "drupal list | grep 'router'" then you will get all router related commands.

I hope this information will help you.